# how to post code object as string in graphene

Tags: python, graphql, graphene-python, graphene-django

i declared my input to be `graphene.string()` but when i put code that includes brackets,slashes,equal signs and other symbol it shows me syntax error , is there any way i could upload mixed string? i have been trying to find solution for the past hours..

sample graphene query that is showing error

```
mutation{
            newForumAnswer(author:"dan",forum:5,body:"hello",code1:"console.log({nrgerg})",code2:"",code3:"",code1Title:"",code2Title:"",code3Title:""){
              answer{
                id
              }
            }
          }
```

Comment: staru from using variables https://graphql.org/learn/queries/ ... then pass string values - escape it if required as request/query/variables must be valid json

Comment: please do show code example

Comment: IDK python :p ... use some online json validator to check your request